# Arrow keys in Firefox 4 not register in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, keyboard, actionscript

Can someone confirm this Flash AS3 question for me? The following code (with a textField on the stage named "textTest") will trace and display on the stage the Key Code of the key pressed. When done within the IDE, and any other browser, it works fine. However, when tested in Firefox 4 (for Mac), everything works except the arrow keys. Can someone confirm and tell me why?

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class test extends MovieClip {


public function test() {
   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler, false, 0, true);
}

private function keyDownHandler($evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
   trace($evt.keyCode);
   textTest.text = String($evt.keyCode);
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you click on the SWF in the browser first? It may be that the SWF doesnt have focus when the page loads, and thus is not receiving the keyboard events.

If that is the case, a simple work around is a "Click Here to Start" button in your content that forces the user to click in the swf.

Answer (score 0):

there have been problem with some later flash versions and firefox 4. Make sure you have the latest flash player version installed:
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

(as I can't comment, I'm going to post this here as well)
It has nothing to do with focus of the SWF. He said that every other key than arrow keys were working, so for the SWF to recieve those other keyinputs, it needs to have focus.

Comment: Im hoping that's it. I can't seem to find any other explanation. I'm using 10.2, so that might be part of the issue as well.